# MongoDB: What exactly $elemMatch does?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is the example Collection:

```json
    {
        id: ID1,
        name: 'ABC',
        child: [
            {
                'key': 'key1',
                'val': 'val1'
            }, {
                'key': 'key2',
                'val': 'val2'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        id: ID2,
        name: 'XYZ',
        child: [
            {
                'key': 'key1',
                'val': 'val1'
            }, {
                'key': 'key3',
                'val': 'val3'
            }, {
                'key': 'key4',
                'val': 'val4'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        id: ID3,
        name: 'PQR',
        child: [
            {
                'key': 'key1',
                'val': 'val1'
            }, {
                'key': 'key2',
                'val': 'val2'
            }, {
                'key': 'key4',
                'val': 'val4'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now let's say, I want to find all the documents, which have `key` as `key1` and `key2`. So in the above example, the query should return documents with `id` `ID1` and `ID3`. I have written three variants of the query to derive specified data, but only one **(#3)** works and others don't. I am not able to figure out what is the exact difference between these three queries:

**Query 1:**

```
{ child: { $elemMatch: {$and: [{ key: 'key1' }, {key: 'key2'}]}  } }
```

**Query 2:**

```
{ child: { $elemMatch: { key: { $all: ['key1', 'key2'] } }  } }
```

**Query 3:** This works!!

```
{ $and: [{'child.key': {$all: ['key1', 'key2']}}]}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the above queries and what exactly `$elemMatch` does?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official document of $elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/),

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with **at least one** element that matches all the specified query criteria.

So for your query 1:

```
{ child: { $elemMatch: {$and: [{ key: 'key1' }, {key: 'key2'}]}  } }
```

It is matching for at least one entry that **both** have `key` as `key1` and `key2`, which is impossible.

For your query 2:

```
{ child: { $elemMatch: { key: { $all: ['key1', 'key2'] } }  } }
```

This doesn't work because it is matching on the field `child` level to see if at least one element contains a single field object `{key: [...]}`, while the `key` field is an array field **AND** contains all `key1` and `key2`. Check out ID4 example in [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QSTbsjKsbAo)

For your query 3,

```
{ $and: [{'child.key': {$all: ['key1', 'key2']}}]}
```

You are checking `child.key` like if it is an array and see if it contains all `key1` and `key2`, so it works. Check out [this official document on dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) for more details.